# How to send user entered details to email in iOS?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uitextfield

I am storing some user details using POST Request ,my question is whatever details user entered those details should  get to my email id. how can i do this ?

**My code is here :**

```
- (IBAction)NextButton:(id)sender {
    NSLog(@"name:%@",nameTextField.text);
    NSLog(@"emailid:%@",emailTextField.text);
    NSLog(@"phonenumber:%@",phoneTextField.text);
    NSLog(@"pickupaddress:%@",addressTextField.text);

    if([nameTextField.text isEqualToString:@""] || [emailTextField.text isEqualToString:@""] || [phoneTextField.text isEqualToString:@""] || [addressTextField.text isEqualToString:@""])

    {
        UIAlertView* alertViewq = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Alert" message:@"Please enter all the details." delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];
        [alertViewq show];

    }

    else
    {
        NSString *post = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"&name=%@&emailid=%@&phonenumber=%@&pickupaddress=%@",nameTextField.text,emailTextField.text,phoneTextField.text,addressTextField.text];
        NSLog(@"post:%@",post);
        NSData *postData = [post dataUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding allowLossyConversion:YES];
        NSString *postLength = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%lu",(unsigned long)[postData length]];


        NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] init];
        [request setURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://example.com/userdetails.php"]]];
        [request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
        [request setValue:postLength forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];
        [request setValue:@"application/x-www-form-urlencoded" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Current-Type"];
        [request setHTTPBody:postData];
        NSURLConnection *theConnection=[[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:request delegate:self];

        if (theConnection)
        {
        }
        else
        {
            UIAlertView* alertView = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Failed" message:@"Check your networking configuration." delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];
            [alertView show];
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Simple answer** : You cant do this within iOS app.

**Solution** : You need to setup email at server side. Whenever user sends any request server can mail this content form back-end. As per my knowledge, this is the only way to achieve your requirements.

I can assume from URL that your server uses php. Please refer following link to mail from php server in back-end.

http://www.w3schools.com/php/func_mail_mail.asp

Hope this may help you.